# How do I rename these files at once?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a bunch of files and I want to rename them using regular expressions.  I want to do this in a Linux Command line.

I have the files

```
report1.txt
report2.txt
report3.txt
```

How can I rename these so that they state

```
myreport1.txt
myreport2.txt
myreport3.txt
```

Please let me know, I've searched the internet and they have many complex examples.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want to use regular expressions. Also, are those the _only_ files you have, or do you want to rename all file that have names ending in `.txt`, or that start with `report`, or just any file that happens to occur in the current directory.  If only those three files, then `mv report1.txt myreport1.txt; mv report2.txt myreport2.txt; mv report3.txt myreport3.txt` would do it.  How would you want to handle name clashes (one or more of the target names already existing, possibly as a directory)?

Comment: Isn't mv used to move files?  I only want to rename just those files using regular expressions.

Comment: Renaming a file is done by moving it to a new name. It's unclear why you think you need to use regular expressions. You may possibly want to use globbing pattern to select the files to process, but there's certainly no need to use a regular expression here. Regular expressions are most commonly used for matching in _text_, and filenames are _not_ text in that same sense (for one, they can't contain `/`, but may contain newlines, which lines in a text can't contain).

Comment: Arslan: Kusalananda has asked you relevant questions, which you don't seem keen to answer. Help us help you.

Comment: Try `rename report myreport report[123].txt` (not tested). This also addresses your aversion of *for* loops and complexity.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate, just use a pattern that matches your files in place of the `*` in the most voted on answer (for example `report*.txt`), then prepend `my` in place of `Unix_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer OP's question in comment: "Is there a way to do it without using a for loop?"

I usually use a dedicated utility for this: `mmv`

```
mmv 'report?.txt' 'myreport#1.txt'
```

(there are several other similar tools around, like `rename`)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use just a simple loop in one line:

```
for ftr in report[0-9]*.txt; do mv "$ftr" "my${ftr}"; done
```

If you don't want use a loop, you can try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "report[0-9]*.txt" -printf "%f\n" | xargs -I{} mv {} my{}
```

Note that, as in the for loop, you need to put this in the path where the files are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mv:

```
for f in *.txt;do mv $f  "my$f"; done
```

Or you can use rename:
you may need to install it based on your distro.

```
rename -v -n 's/report/myreport/' *.txt
```

rename (option*) 's/oldname/newname/' file1 file2 or use *.extension

If you are on Archlinux use this if that didn't work:

```
rename -v report myreport *.txt
```

For options check man rename

Comment: The first variation is a broken variant of the answer that [mondo-cane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634616/116858) gave.

Comment: @ Kusalananda I am not here to argue but for mondo-cane it seems the time "answered 2 hours ago". However, we are here to help I am not to Compete.

Answer (score 1):

In the `zsh` shell, the following would rename the three files shown:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -v -- 'report<1-3>.txt' 'my$f'
```

The source pattern should be a valid `zsh` extended globbing pattern (quoted), and the source pattern used here simply matches the three filenames that you mentioned.

The `$f` in the target pattern will be replaced by the full original filename.  One could also use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to refer to any parenthesized capture groups in the source pattern (there are none used here as it's not needed).

From the `bash` shell (passing the source and target patterns to the `zsh -c` shell as arguments):

```
zsh -c 'autoload -U zmv; zmv -v -- $1 $2' zsh 'report<1-3>.txt' 'my$f'
```

This answer ignores the issue of name collisions.